# Setting sensitivity label for excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, com, openpyxl

I was trying to load a dataframe into an excel template using openpyxl and save it at the highest sensitivity setting. The template has 5 levels of sensitivity set by the Microsoft admins, with the highest level being "Highly Protected". [Pic for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKpea.png)

The template is saved as "Highly Protected" but once the data is loaded in, the new file reverts to "General Business" label.

```
# Load template file
template_path = filepath.xlsx
tmpwb = openpyxl.load_workbook(template_path)

#   select sheet
sheet = tmpwb['Data']

# update columns names
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    sheet.cell(row=2, column=i+1).value = col

# update main data table
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    for j, df_value in enumeratedf[col]):
        sheet.cell(row=j+3, column=i+1).value = df_value

file_path = savepath.xlsx

# save workbook
tmpwb.save(file_path)
```

Is there a way I can control the sensitivity settings using python? Thanks for any tips.

Comment: The sensitivity parameter does not sound like an excel-specific item. I think you should look into modifying the sensitivity parameter of the file in windows after you have saved it. Perhaps a batch file?

Answer (score 1):

The sensitivity label is Office365 Parameter which can be modified with xlwings and the pywin32 API.

The only thing you need to do first is to find out the individual ID's of the classifications.

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('test.xlsx') #A workbook with a set activity label

labelinfo = wb.api.SensitivityLabel.GetLabel()
print(labelinfo.LabelId)
>>> 123123123-123123123-ajskldfj123  (as an example ID, this will look different for each LabelName)
```

This will give you the ID of the Sensitivity Label, which you can then pass to the modified xls at the end. This will look different for each LabelName. So you will first (one time action) need to find out your Company's ID for these Sensitivity Labels
Then you set the Label, like below:

```
wb = xw.Book('test.xlsx')
labelinfo = wb.api.SensitivityLabel.CreateLabelInfo()
labelinfo.AssignmentMethod = 2
labelinfo.Justification = 'init'
labelinfo.LabelId = 'YOUR-ID-GOES-HERE'
wb.api.SensitivityLabel.SetLabel(labelinfo, labelinfo)
```

This should set your Sensitivity label correctly.

You can learn more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.sensitivitylabel?source=recommendations)

Answer (score 0):

For our use case, the sensitivity labels are treated as custom properties. I am not sure if all sensitivity labels are handled this way. You can access custom properties using openpyxl using the following: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/workbook_custom_doc_props.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35687314)